# Trying to login to a website with java.net but not sure how to handle cookies

Tags: java, cookies

I keep getting "Your session timed out" when trying to login and I suspect its due to cookies not being handled at all. Would HTTPS stop me from logging in via Java?

Here is the code:

```
package logintopage;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LoginToPage{

// Variables to hold the URL object and its connection to that URL.
private static URL URLObj;
private static URLConnection connect;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Establish a URL and open a connection to it. Set it to output mode.
        URLObj = new URL("my url");
        connect = URLObj.openConnection();
        connect.setDoOutput(true);  


    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("The URL specified was unable to be parsed or uses an invalid protocol. Please try again.");
        System.exit(1); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("An exception occurred. " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }


    try {

        // Create a buffered writer to the URLConnection's output stream and write our forms parameters.
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connect.getOutputStream()));

        writer.write("userIdentifier=user&password=pass&LoginUser=Sign+In");
        writer.close();

        // Now establish a buffered reader to read the URLConnection's input stream.
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

        String lineRead = "";

        // Read all available lines of data from the URL and print them to screen.
        while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(lineRead);
        }

        reader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("There was an error reading or writing to the URL: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm fairly new to the world of networking in Java so help as well as info sources are much appreciated.

Comment: The full stacktrace would help us to diagnose the causes...

Answer (score 0):

The code above would work only for http connections.

If you need to connect to a url over https, then you would need to use the SSLSocket and SSLSocketFactory classes.  Take a look at this basic example: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=32388 or maybe http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/java-security-tutorial-step-by-step-guide-to-create-ssl-connection-and-certificates.html

You might also consider simplifying your code to be:

URLObj = new URL("my_url?userIdentifier=user&password=pass&LoginUser=Sign+In");